# Can a trigger for a table can be applied for tracking in same table?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Can a trigger for a table can be applied for tracking in same table?

That is IF I have table Say "employee" Now can i create a triggers such that it tracks the change in the same "employee" table

trigger such as

```
create trigger "<triggers_name>"  before insert on employee
For each row
Begin
 insert into employee field = timestamp;
end
```

Comment: That syntax looks pretty wrong.  I know you can do it in Oracle, and I think you can do it in MySQL, but I would recommend against it.  It sounds like you want a default value in a date field instead of a trigger.

Comment: I agree with MJB. So maybe you should explain what you intend to do exactly, because your example looks weird.

Comment: Yes it is weird but I got the reply by Mr.Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

So let's think about this.

A "before" trigger will execute before the action (in this case, an "insert" action) takes place.

***If*** this were to work, and you attempted to do an insert into the employee table every time an insert took place on the employee table, you'd loop forever in a big recursive mess.

Referenced from the MySQL docs

> "Within a stored function or trigger,
>   it is not permitted to modify a table
>   that is already being used (for
>   reading or writing) by the statement
>   that invoked the function or trigger."

See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) for more info.

---

That said, if you need to do tracking when inserts take place, I would recommend using a second table which can certainly be referenced via a trigger.  You and create a FK to the employee table and put your timestamp column in that new table and do something like this:

```
for each row
insert into employee_tracking (id, timestamp) on duplicate key update set timestamp = new_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to track the insert time, you can have your datefield default to NOW().

I wonder if you can do an update on a table that was just inserted? The recursion I understand with the second insert but maybe you can update the same table?